# Деление с получением дроби

Tags: c#

Я не понимаю, как это загуглить, ткните пальцем.

Есть формула, в формулу подставляются числа. С числами выглядит так

```
double qwe = ((100 / (((70 / 1237) * 100) + ((2 / 6) * 100) / 2)) * 0.75)
```

Но при выполнении я получаю ошибку деления на ноль, хотя должен получить 3.359. Как быть?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Как быть?

Избегать целочисленного деления.

```
double qwe = ((100 / (((70 / 1237.0) * 100) + ((2 / 6.0) * 100) / 2)) * 0.75);
                                 ^^                  ^^
```